How do I configure US layout with German special characters (on Fedora/GNOME/wayland)?
On a Fedora installation running GNOME under Wayland, I want to achieve the following:

regular US ANSI layout
international keys / unicode keys on Right Alt+key (I really only need the German ones and maybe the Euro symbol)
no dead keys

This is one of the layouts available on KDE and it's perfect for anyone with a US keyboard who needs european characters and wants to do coding. But there is no such layout on GNOME.
Does anyone know how I can configure it?

I do the following in xinitrc: setxkbmap -layout "us,bg(phonetic)" -option "grp:switch" to be able to type in my language with AltGr.

You have two options to change your keyboard layout. If you want to make your own keyboard layout, see this and that.
1. Via GNOME settings
Install gnome-tweaks to enable "Show Extended Input Sources" in the Keyboard tab or run gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true. Restart GNOME by logging out.
Then, go to the "Keyboard" tab in GNOME settings, click on "Add input source", click on "English", then scroll down and add the "German, Swedish, and Finnish (US)" layout. This layout allows you to type "@€üöå~äß|ÜÖÅÄẞ¦" using the right alt key.
2. Via command line
Open a terminal and type
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources "[('xkb', 'us+de_se_fi')]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us+de_se_fi')]"


This: "German, Swedish, and Finnish (US)" doesn't show up for me. I'm on GNOME 46.6.

@HendrikHübner I edited my answer. Try again.

I chose the "English (intl, with AltGr Dead Keys)" Keyboard layout in Gnome. That way I have the "normal" American keyboard, and have "ä" on AltGr-q, "ö" on AltGr-p, "ß" on AltGr-s, "ü" on AltGr-y. So reachable without using the dead-keys.
